# React: Calling filter on Object.keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

A React component is passed a state property, which is an object of objects:

```
{
    things: {
        1: {
            name: 'fridge',
            attributes: []
        },
        2: {
            name: 'ashtray',
            attributes: []
        }
    }
}
```

It is also passed (as a router parameter) a `name`. I want the component to find the matching object in the `things` object by comparing `name` values.

To do this I use the `filter` method:

```
Object.keys(this.props.things).filter((id) => {
    if (this.props.things[id].name === this.props.match.params.name) console.log('found!');
    return (this.props.things[id].name === this.props.match.params.name);
});
```

However this returns `undefined`. I know the condition works because of my test line (the `console.log` line), which logs `found` to the console. Why does the `filter` method return `undefined`?

Comment: Can you show the whole code where you use this snippet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns an array of keys (like maybe `["2"]` in your case). 
If you are interested in retrieving the matching *object*, then you really need `Object.values`. And if you are expecting one result, and not an array of them, then use `find` instead of `filter`:

```
Object.values(this.props.things).find((obj) => {
    if (obj.name === this.props.match.params.name) console.log('found!');
    return (obj.name === this.props.match.params.name);
});
```

Be sure to `return` that result if you use it within a function. Here is a snippet based on the fiddle you provided in comments:

```js
var state = {
    things: {
        1: {
            name: 'fridge',
            attributes: []
        },
        2: {
            name: 'ashtray',
            attributes: []
        }
    }
};

var findThing = function(name) {
  return Object.values(state.things).find((obj) => {
      if (obj.name === name) console.log('found!');
      return obj.name === name;
  });
}

var result = findThing('fridge');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks - this does indeed seem like a better way of doing it. But I still can't see what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Maybe you address the result with property references that do not exist in the result. Or maybe you call this code multiple times where only sometimes you get the `console.log` output. It is impossible to tell without more context. Could you provide a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Obviously a function that does not `return` will return `undefined`.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the help. If you want to put that in your answer I'll mark it right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result of filter to a object and you get the result as the `[id]`. You then need to get the object as `this.props.things[id]`

```js
var data = {
    things: {
        1: {
            name: 'fridge',
            attributes: []
        },
        2: {
            name: 'ashtray',
            attributes: []
        }
    }
}

var name = 'fridge';
var newD = Object.keys(data.things).filter((id) => {
    if (data.things[id].name === name) console.log('found!');
    return (data.things[id].name === name);
});

console.log(data.things[newD]);
```